# How to use igraph vertex.shape functionality

Tags: r, plot, shapes, vertex, igraph

Has anyone used igraph's vertex.shape functionality?  This http://cneurocvs.rmki.kfki.hu/igraph/doc/R/igraph.vertex.shapes.html was promising but I could not understand.  Does anyone have an example of working code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The verticies are just the nodes in your graph.  When you plot them you can have them as rectangles or circles or some other shapes.  Whatever you think looks prettiest.

Start by looking at the example on the `?igraph.vertex.shapes` page.

```
g <- graph.ring(10, dir=TRUE, mut=TRUE)
plot(g, vertex.shape="rectangle", layout=layout.circle)
```

The allowed values for the `vertex.shape` argument are given by

```
names(igraph:::.igraph.shapes)
[1] "circle"     "square"     "csquare"    "rectangle"  "crectangle"
[6] "vrectangle" "none"
```

See `?layout` for the allowed values for the `layout` argument.

Comment: 1st thx for the fruitful answer. `names(igraph:::.igraph.shapes)` produces `NULL` in my console though I have `igraph` package and loaded it already. There is a redirect for `?igraph.vertex.shapes` as well, it redirects to `http://127.0.0.1:27356/library/igraph/html/shapes.html`